# Using parent function with & from directive for custom behavior, but need a callback?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to make a small directive that allows for either a simple text area, or an option that makes it a non-editable div until a pencil icon is clicked, at which point, the textarea is displayed so the content can be edited.  Save functionality needs to be defined by the parent controller.

my invocation of the directives is as follows:

```
<body ng-controller="AppController">
  <my-dir togglesave=true contents="one" savecontents="savecontents(one)"></my-dir>
  <my-dir togglesave=true contents="two" savecontents="savecontents(two)"></my-dir>
  <my-dir contents="three" savecontents="savecontents(three)"></my-dir>
</body>
```

here's the js:

```
    var app = angular.module('my-app', [], function() {

    })

    app.controller('AppController', function($scope) {

      $scope.one = "one";
  $scope.two = "two";
  $scope.three = "three";

  $scope.savecontents = function(obj){
    alert(obj);
  }

})

app.directive('myDir', function() {
  return {
    required: '^ngModel',
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      contents: '=',
      togglesave: '=',
      savecontents: '&'
    },
    templateUrl: 'template.html',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

      scope.pencil = false;

    }
  };
})`
```

here's the template:

```
<div ng-show="editing || !togglesave">
  <textarea ng-model="contents"></textarea>
</div>
<div ng-mouseenter="pencil = true" ng-mouseleave="pencil= false" ng-show="!editing && togglesave">{{contents}}
<button ng-show="pencil" ng-click="editing = true"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
</div>
<span ng-show="editing"><button ng-click="savecontents()">save</button></span>
```

i need for the savecontents function defined in the parent to somehow let the directive know that it's done saving, so that the "editing" flag can be set to false, and the textarea and save button hidden, and the non editable div show.  i'm relatively new to angular, and am not sure if i'm going about this the right way.

any assistance appreciated :)

[Here's a Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/eIWf8E3qJu0aSGDeM8Ou?p=preview)

one and two are defined as having this toggling behavior.  three is just the textarea.

the bonus question is that the contents might be a complex object depending on who's calling it.  i'd like the directive to know about the whole object, because the display might be a particular parameter.  but the save function might need to know about the object as a whole.  is there an easy way to do that?  like - if content is a primitive, just display that, but if it's an object, tell the directive what parameter should be displayed, while allowing the save function to have information about the full object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Third element not showing toggling behavior is because you are not passing   togglesave attribute as true for the third element.

```
    <my-dir togglesave=true contents="one" savecontents="savecontents(one)"></my-dir>
  <my-dir togglesave=true contents="two" savecontents="savecontents(two)"></my-dir>
  <my-dir contents="three" savecontents="savecontents(three)"></my-dir>
```

So, tooglesave attribute is going undefined in the directive's scope in the template.html and !undefined = true so it is showing the text area instead of toggling behavior.

```
<div ng-show="editing || !togglesave">
  <textarea ng-model="contents"></textarea>
</div>
```

2) The template.html file is bound to the 'my-dir' directive's scope. You don't have create savecontents function as attribute for your directive and then pass it from the parent controller, since you already have access to the objects you are passing from the parent controller in the contents attribute inside your directive's scope.

All you have to do is write a function in your directive on click of save button, which makes the editing flag as false and whatever you want to do with the objects.So your app.js and index.html will change to something like this:

```
    var app = angular.module('my-app', [], function() {

    })
    app.controller('AppController', function($scope) {

      $scope.one = "one";
      $scope.two = "two";
      $scope.three = "three";

// Passing this function to the directive savecontents attributed so that this function can be executed by the directive. 
    $scope.savecontents1 = function(obj){
        //saving data for obj 1
       alert(obj);
      }

      $scope.savecontents2 = function(obj){
        //saving data for obj 1
        alert(obj);
      }

      $scope.savecontents3 = function(obj) {
        //saving data for obj 1
        alert(obj);
      };

    })

    app.directive('myDir', function() {
      return {
        required: '^ngModel',
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
          contents: '=',
          togglesave: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'template.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {


     // Calling the savedata method from the directive's template (template.html) on click of save button
     scope.savedata = function() {
        // It will execute the function passed from the parent controller.
           scope.savecontents();
          scope.editing = false;
     }

        }
      };
    })
```

And your index.html

```
    <my-dir togglesave=true contents="one" savecontents="savecontents1(one)"></my-dir>
  <my-dir togglesave=true contents="two" savecontents="savecontents2(two)"></my-dir>
  <my-dir togglesave=true contents="three" savecontents="savecontents3(three)"></my-dir>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: thank you very much for your response :)  

the reason i am trying to have the parent execute the save is that the directive may be tasked with displaying some property of an object.  some consumers may just pass a string.  some may pass a complex object.  the saving steps will be different for those two things.  does that make sense?  if it is not possible to have the object type be generic, does it make sense to have a different directive per object type, so the save function can be defined in the directive as you suggest?

Comment: Hi, There is no need to create a different directive for every object type.  I am passing the save function(savecontents1, savecontents2) definition from the parent controller into the directive's scope via the savecontents attribute. And executing the function inside the directives scope on click of the save button. I have edited the post. This should cover your use case. Please have a look.